# Making collisions work in Apple SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, collision-detection, game-physics

Im trying to write an a simple application in Xcode - fallDown game - and I need to make the ball collide with the platforms.

First - I tried using animator and adding a collider and gravity and such but then i couldn't get the frame to be circular (that would be very helpful if someone could show me that).

Second - Because the above didn't work (something to do with UIbezierpath) I decided to use SpriteKit.  With spriteKit you make objects/nodes.  The ball and platforms are skshapenodes which i need to collide using ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask but everyTime i run the ball goes through the body

```
static const uint32_t ballCategory = 0x11 << 1;
static const uint32_t platformCategory = 0x11 << 3;

+ (SKNode *) spawnBall
{
    SKShapeNode *node = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, BALL_RADIUS, BALL_RADIUS)];

    node.path = [path CGPath];
    node.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    node.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    //node.glowWidth = BALL_GLOW_RADIUS;

    node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
    node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = platformCategory;
    return node;
}
+ (NSMutableArray *) risingPlats
{
    // Screen Size
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat width = screenBound.size.width;
    CGFloat height = screenBound.size.height;

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfShapes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int numberPieces = arc4random() % 2;
    if (numberPieces) {
        SKShapeNode * node = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];

        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:
                              CGRectMake((BALL_RADIUS*3-width)/2, -height, width-(BALL_RADIUS*3), BALL_RADIUS)];

        node.path = [path CGPath];
        node.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        node.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

        node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = platformCategory;
        node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory;

        [arrayOfShapes addObject:node];
    } else {
        int locationOfHole = (arc4random() % (int)(width-(BALL_RADIUS*6)))+BALL_RADIUS*1.5;

        // node1
        SKShapeNode * node = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:
                              CGRectMake((-width/2), -height, locationOfHole, BALL_RADIUS)];

        node.path = [path CGPath];
        node.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        node.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

        node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = platformCategory;
        node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory;

        [arrayOfShapes addObject:node];

        // node2
        SKShapeNode *node2 = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
        UIBezierPath *path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:
                              CGRectMake(locationOfHole+BALL_RADIUS*3-(width/2), -height, width-(locationOfHole+BALL_RADIUS*3), BALL_RADIUS)];

        node2.path = [path2 CGPath];
        node2.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        node2.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

        node2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = platformCategory;
        node2.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory;

        [arrayOfShapes addObject:node2];
    }
    return arrayOfShapes;
}
```

I changed the above to contactbitmask and when i implemented the method for two bodies contacting it never printed to console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your nodes dont have a physicsbody assigned to them.

you're assigning them physicsbody categories, but they have no physicsbody to begin with.  It's nil!

you need to do

```
yournode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody <some initializer>]
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if i add the physics bodies later?

Comment: I add it in the scene but this is just spawning the nodes (spawner class)

Comment: Ok that might solve my problem because i need a physicsBody on the plats but i originally never added it because they react to gravity now.  How do i turn off gravity for one object

Comment: There is an affectedbygravity property. You can try that

Comment: Also the collisions are not nice... they act really squishy for some reason and objects can pass through each other

Comment: your question wasnt how to make nodes not affected by gravity, or how to make your collisions non-squashy.  It was how to make your collisions work.  If I answered that for you then you should mark the answer as correct. Maybe create a new question about the collisions themselves.